# how to append the string in two different data table cell by cell?

Tags: r, data-processing, data-wrangling

I have two tables: table 1 and table 2 and I want the output as below

table 1

```
col 1   col 2  col 3 

1        0      2
 
3        2      1

5        3      2
```

table 2

```
col 1   col 2  col 3 

1        2      3
 
2        3      1

3        1      2
```

Output I want is....

```
col1 col2 col3 

11    02   23

32    23   11

53    31   22
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

table1 <- tribble(
~col1,   ~col2,  ~col3, 
1, 0, 2, 
3, 2, 1, 
5, 3, 2)

table2 <- tribble(
  ~col1,   ~col2,  ~col3, 
  1, 2, 3, 
  2, 3, 1, 
  3, 1, 2)


table3 <- table1 %>% 
  mutate(col1 = paste(table1$col1, table2$col1, sep = ""),
         col2 = paste(table1$col2, table2$col2, sep = ""),
         col3 = paste(table1$col3, table2$col3, sep = ""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Map` :

```
table1[] <- Map(paste0, table1, table2)
table1

#  col1 col2 col3
#1   11   02   23
#2   32   23   11
#3   53   31   22
```

If the columns have the same type you can also use `as.matrix` without `Map`.

```
table1[] <- paste0(as.matrix(table1), as.matrix(table2))
```

**data**

```
table1 <- structure(list(col1 = c(1, 3, 5), col2 = c(0, 2, 3), col3 = c(2, 
1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

table2 <- structure(list(col1 = c(1, 2, 3), col2 = c(2, 3, 1), col3 = c(3, 
1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak. Is `Map` = `map` from `purr` package?

Comment: `Map` (uppercase `M`) is base R, `map` (lowercase `m`) is `purrr`. I am using `Map` from base R here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach, using `paste0`. The data was not provided, so using `mtcars` data:

```
df1 <- mtcars[, c(2, 8, 9)]
df2 <- mtcars[, c(9, 10, 11)]

names(df1) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")
names(df2) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")

df3 <- data.frame("col1" = paste0(df1$col1, df2$col1),
                  "col2" = paste0(df1$col2, df2$col2),
                  "col3" = paste0(df1$col3, df2$col3))
head(df3)
  col1 col2 col3
1   61   04   14
2   61   04   14
3   41   14   11
4   60   13   01
5   80   03   02
6   60   13   01
```